# Слово "актуализуется"

Tags: грамотная-речь

"В настоящее время как никогда актуализуется задача выработки линии уголовного законодательства" — корректно «актуализуется»?

Answer (score 1):

В языке есть  два глагола *актуализовать(ся) и актуализировать(ся)*(делать(ся) актуальным).  Мне кажется, раньше в язык вошел глагол *актуализировать* как двувидовой (совершенного и несовершенного вида) - именно так он зафиксирован в Большом толковом словаре Кузнецова (есть и в других словарях 80-х годов ).  Слова актуализовать в них нет. А в Толковом словаре иноязычных слов Крысина есть оба глагола с пометой совершенный (актуализировать) и несовершенный вид (актуализовать). В Вашем примере слово употреблено верно.

Answer (score 0):

Это предложение некорректно само по себе, так как по смысловому значению является набором слов типа "зеленая ярость воет адекватно". И даже если вы замените "актуализируется" на другое слово, корректней звучать не станет.

Comment: Не надо таких далеких аналогий. Тем более - бессодержательно. Какие крнкретно слова по-вашему несут лексическую несочетаемость?  "Выработка линии" или "линия законодателства"? и то и другое лично мне представляется вполне возможным.

Тут другое. Четыре родительных подряд. Может, именно это вас и смутило.

Comment: У меня при прочтении этой фразы возникает ряд вопросов. 
Почему автор написал, что задача выработки линии уголовного законодательства актуализируется в настоящее время? А что - до этого ничего не вырабатывалось и не существовало Римского права и Русской правды? Почему автор написал, что в настоящее время как никогда актуализируется? Почему автор решил, что, к примеру, пять лет назад этот вопрос был менее важным? Что автор подразумевает, употребляя словосочетание "линия законодательства"? И, наконец, уголовное законодательство. Есть законодательство вообще, оно подразделяется на отрасли права.

Comment: Ваши вопросы не связаны с русским языком. Предметную область тут не обсуждают.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно, хотя я бы предпочел "актуализируется". Субъективно звeчит лучше.

Но за оборотец "задача выработки линии уголовного законодательства" надо расстреливать без суда и следствия. Два "нанизанных" родительных падежа - уже плохо. Четыре - ни в какие ворота не лезет.

Answer (score 0):

1. Говоря формально, словоупотребление правильно.

Но понятнее и ближе к живой речи будет сказать не "актуализуется", а "актуальна":

"В настоящее время как никогда актуальна задача выработки линии уголовного законодательства."

2. Оборот "выработки линии уголовного законодательства" кажется мне излишне утяжелённым.  Слово "линии" можно бы было убрать без ущерба для смысла:

"В настоящее время как никогда актуальна задача выработки уголовного законодательства."